# How to determine the intermediate fields when it is not Galois?

Tags: galois-theory

I was considering the following example, let $K=\mathbb{F}_2(t)$ and $L=\mathbb{F}_2(t)[X]/(X^2-t)$. If I am not mistaken, $L$ would be a degree two extension of $K$ and this is famously not separable. Now we know that this is not in a position to apply all the nice theorems from Galois Theory. Nevertheless, I was wondering if we had to compute its intermediate fields, what strategies can we use?(In particular, we know that the number of intermediate fields will not necessarily be finite.)

As we have both $t$ and $X$ going on, I am a bit perplexed about what the intermediate fields could look like. My gut instinct is to say there is only one intermediate field, generated by $X$, in $L$ over $K$ but I am not sure how true that is.

Many thanks for any helps!

Comment: In this particular case, there are several considerations to use. The most obvious, of course, is degree. Since $[L:K]$ is a prime number, there are no fields at all properly between the two. A more interesting consideration is that when $K$ is of transcendence degree one over a perfect field of characteristic $p>0$ (as here), then over $K$, there is precisely one totally inseparable extension field of degree $p^m$, namely $K^{1/p^m}$.